Sticky cells in header in MUI
I have table made with MUI. Problem: I can't make all the header to be sticky. It only makes sticky
雇用形態, 応募経路 and months cells. But "FY23" is completely ignored and always hidden when scrolling. Can it be fixed?
`const ScrollableTable = ({ data }) => {
const counts = processData(data);
const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 1366px)');
return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper} style={{ maxHeight: 500 }}>
        <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table" style={{ minWidth: isSmallScreen ? 650 : '100%' }}>
            <TableHead>
            <StyledTableRow>
                    <StyledTableCell colSpan={14} align="center" style={{ backgroundColor: '#3c3e42', color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '1.2rem' }}>
                        内定者一覧
                    </StyledTableCell>
                </StyledTableRow>
                <StyledTableRow>
                    <StyledTableCell rowSpan={3} align="center">雇用形態</StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell rowSpan={3} align="center">応募経路</StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell colSpan={12} align="center" aria-label="sticky table">FY23</StyledTableCell>
                </StyledTableRow>
                <StyledTableRow>
                    {japaneseMonths.map(month => (
                        <StyledTableCell key={`month-${month}`}>{month}</StyledTableCell>
                    ))}
                </StyledTableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
                {Object.keys(counts).map((category) => (
                    <React.Fragment key={`category-${category}`}>
                        <StyledTableRow key={`category-row-${category}`}>
                            <StyledTableCell rowSpan={10} align="center">{category}</StyledTableCell>
                            <StyledTableCell>{'全体数'}</StyledTableCell>
                            {counts[category]['全体数'].map((count, idx) => (
                                <StyledTableCell key={`total-${category}-${idx}`}>{count}</StyledTableCell>
                            ))}
                        </StyledTableRow>
                        {Object.keys(counts[category]).filter(route => route !== '全体数').map((route) => (
                            <StyledTableRow
                                key={`route-${category}-${route}`}
                                sx={{ backgroundColor: route === '入社確定' ? '#fabf34' : 'inherit' }}
                            >
                                <StyledTableCell>{route}</StyledTableCell>
                                {counts[category][route].map((count, idx) => (
                                    <StyledTableCell key={`route-count-${category}-${route}-${idx}`}>{count}</StyledTableCell>
                                ))}
                            </StyledTableRow>
                        ))}
                    </React.Fragment>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
    </TableContainer>
);

};`
I did not found anything in documentation about it. Nor anything in the Internet.
